# OnLoad on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose, as exercise, we have to dynamically adjust a `div` `height` to the one of the previous `div`.

My question is how to apply that on the "onload" of the element, in order to have each div's individul previous element...

Suppose the code

```js
$(".description").css("height", 
                      $(".description").prev(".pic").height());
```

```css
.pic {float: left; width: 50%; border: 1px solid red;}
.description {border: 1px dotted green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <figure>
    <div class="pic">pic1<br>this is a big pic</div>
    <div class="description">one is OK</div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="pic">pic2<br>this<br> is a pic2<br>this is another big pic</div>
    <div class="description">two is NOK</div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
  etc...
  </figure>
</div>
```

you can see, the code works only for the first `description`, the second description is still adjusted to the first one.

**PS.**

Please *do not propose to reformat the HTML*, I am wondering how to apply some JS code for a specific HTML element: ***something like to have "onload" on a div element, to correctly identify the previous element***.

Comment: $(".description").each().css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `.css()` can be passed a function:

```
$(".description").css("height", function() {
  var element = this; // current "description" element
  return $(element).prev(".pic").height() + "px";
});
```

The value of `this` inside the callback function will be, in turn, each element that matches the selector (`".description"`).

Answer (score 1):

This code will do, you need to iterate through all the .pics

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".description").each(function(){
    var height = $(this).parent().find('.pic').height();
    $(this).css('height',height);
  })
});
```